# Combine SvelteKit's throw Redirect with Felte's onSuccess

Tags: sveltekit

**The problem:**

Nothing happends when throwing `throw redirect(302, '/auth/sign-up-success')` in SvelteKit's actions if `onSuccess: () => {...}` is set in Felte's `createForm({...})`.

**Example:**

```js
// +page.server.ts
export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async (event) => {
        ...
        throw redirect(302, '/auth/sign-up-success');
    }
}
```

```js
// SignUpForm.svelte
const { form, errors } = createForm({
    onSuccess: (response) => {
        invalidate('app:auth')
    },
    ...
}
```

If I would delete the onSuccess part, then redirect would happend.

**Question:**

Is there a way to reuse that redirect form success response logic from default Felte form config without writing it again myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Action responses are JSON objects with a type, you could read the response and redirect on the client:

```js
async onSuccess(response) {
    const { type, location } = await response.json();
    if (type == 'redirect') {
        goto(location); // from '$app/navigation'
        return;
    }
}
```

I would not recommend using this library though. It appears to be incompatible with SSR and one of its main actions shares the name of the `form` data property used by SvelteKit form actions.

Depending on why you are using this, there might be more suitable tools for SvelteKit in particular (if you even need any, SvelteKit does many things out of the box).

Comment: Any third party libs you would recommend to take a look at?

Comment: Not as of yet. I just use native HTML form validation mechanism and have found no use for such libraries.

Comment: Well, you were right. Just used zod for validations as a lib. Everything else - native sveltekit. Code is way cleaner now. Felte uninstalled. Thanks for advice @H.B.